# Join where value of one table in list of values from other table

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, I have `table1` which has a (not nullable) column `id` which is always a 5-digit integer. I want to join it with `table2` which also has a column `id` which is (nullable) strings of these same IDs.

The trouble is that `id` in `table2` can also be a list of ' / ' seperated IDs.

Here is an example of the column:

```
82795 
82795
NULL 
84660 
84120 / 82795 
73844 / 73845 
73844 / 73845 
NULL
83793 / 84758 
73844 / 73845 / 84122 / 84136 
73844 / 73845 / 84136 
84845
```

How can I achieve something with similar logic to:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id IN SPLIT(table2.id, ' / ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with what Tim says about normalising your table, but in the interim you should be able to use `IN` with `UNNEST` to search the results of `SPLIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id IN UNNEST(SPLIT(table2.id, ' / '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider normalizing your second table such that each `id` value appears on a separate record.  As a workaround to your current situation, you may try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON CONCAT(' ', t2.id, ' ') LIKE CONCAT('% ', CAST(t1.id AS STRING), ' %');
```

The above `ON` clause is a trick which searches for a table1 `id` somewhere in the table2 `id`.  It works by padding the latter with spaces, such that we only need to search for a table1 `id` surrounded by spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Nick, but I think this version works better in BigQuery:

```
with table1 as (
       select 82795 as id union all
       SELECT 1234 UNION ALL
       SELECT 84122
     ),
     table2 as (
       SELECT '84120 / 82795' as id UNION ALL
       SELECT '73844 / 73845 / 84122 / 84136'
     )
SELECT t1, t2
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN 
     (table2 t2 CROSS JOIN
      UNNEST(SPLIT(t2.id, ' / ')) t2id
     )
     ON t1.id = safe_cast(t2id as int64);
```

(The above works.)

Notes:

- BigQuery complains when I don't use `=` for `LEFT JOIN`.
- I assume that `table1.id` is a number.  String need to be converted for the comparison.
- Duplicate column names are not allowed in a `SELECT`, so `SELECT *` doesn't work.  The easy workaround is to select the values as records rather than as columns.